# Font Color in Adobe Acrobat - Javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, fonts, acrobat, adobe-indesign

I created an editable PDF through Adobe Indesign. The editable text is in a text field and after exporting and opening in Adobe Acrobat I am able to edit text however it only uses black for the font color. I was able to find a bit of code online to edit said text through Javascript which changes font size and family, however I'm struggling to find a way to edit the color of the font. I'm trying to get the color to be white and my knowledge of Javascript is minimal/non existant[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqioc.png), any help is much appreciated!

My code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numFields; i++) {

    var fName = getNthFieldName(i);

    var f = getField(fName);

    if (f.type === "text") {

//      f.alignment ="center";

        f.textSize = 75;

        f.textFont = "DINLIGHT";
        f.textcolor = ["CMYK","1.0 1.0 1.0"];

    ;
 
// Other properties go here
    
    }

}
```

I was trying to get my font color to change to white and allow others to edit this PDF and keep the same font size and family. It's currently black and everything I've tried doesn't work

```
f.textcolor = "white";

f.textcolor = ["CMYK","0, 0, 0, 0"];
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmAx2.png)

Comment: From what I can recall, you have to set the fillColor, and the color has to be added to the document, before you can use it.

Comment: `f.textcolor = ["CMYK","1.0 1.0 1.0"];` is not going to work for sure as it's missing a colour. maybe `f.textcolor = ["RGB",1.0, 1.0, 1.0];`?

Answer (score 0):

I dont use JS so for exact editing syntax in Acrobat your on your own, however to show you the target here is a mock total mash-up

[image]
[image]

2 alternate decompressed forms are temporarily at https://transfer.sh/uX23WO/fillme%20101.zip

TRY file 101 first and note it changes appearance, then try 111 and see if opening 101.pdf in a WordPad explains in RGb terms what `/DA(1 0 1 rg` does for form entry

Then you may well ask that explains a new colour change, but what about existing pre-filled colour, then you need to look at and file compare  https://transfer.sh/LTNPhM/fillme%20100.pdf

Now you have some idea why re-molding existing PDFs it is not easy to say where a change will need to be applied.